# Javascript animations jerky

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I've tried using both jQuery's .animate and velocity.js to perform circular movement. However no matter what I do the animation is jerky - you can see the elements snapping to a pixel grid; you can for example see the elements moving one pixel to the right, and one pixel down afterwards. What causes this issue? Is it possible to make the animation smooth, maybe by using some third party plugin or some sort of interpolation?

Here's my movement code:

```
function animateElement(element) {
    var xPos = parentCenter.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius;
    var yPos = parentCenter.y + Math.sin(angle) * radius;

    $.Velocity(element,
        {top: xPos , left: yPos },
        {duration: animationTime, easing:"linear",
            complete: function () {
                animateElement(element);
            }
    });
}
```

Here's my jsfiddle: [circular movement](http://jsfiddle.net/k0v9ja8e/)

Thanks!

Comment: check this site out and watch the youtube video on animations, i thought it would help: http://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, so I'll post it as a comment. If you change all of your 1000ms durations to something around 200-ish, it's still very easy to read and moves a little faster which makes it not appear as 'jerk-y'.  Just some thoughts..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `left` and `top` for you animation you should use `translateX` and `translateY`. This not only will use hardware acceleration, but  should activate the sub-pixel movement.

You should also make sure to round the numbers to something like four decimals.

<kbd>**[jsfiddle - demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4c5258sq/)**</kbd> (One `div` with `left`/`top` the other one with `translateX`/`translateY`)

[Paul Irish: Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)